# Serializing Django. How to set custom template

Tags: django

**Good day!** Trying to figure out how to **generate xml** in Django

**What do i have?** Objects that appear on the site. The data of these objects must be generated in **special fields** in the **xml** file.

I created `views.py`:

```
def xml(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)
    listings = serializers.serialize('xml', listings)
    context = { 'listings': listings }
    return HttpResponse(listings, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

As a result, I get:

```
<django-objects version="1.0">
    <object model="listings.Listing" pk="1">
    <field name="price" type="IntegerField">100</field>
    </object>
    <object model="listings.Listing" pk="2">
    <field name="price" type="IntegerField">100</field>
    </object>
</django-objects>
```

As I understand it, this is a standard template in Django

**Question!** How to specify a **custom template** so that all markup is implemented by me, for example:

```
<offer id="1">
    <price>100</price>
</offer>
<offer id="2">
    <price>100</price>
</offer>
```

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with templates. That's just the output of the XML serializer.

If you don't like it, serialize it yourself from Python objects:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

listings = Listing.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)
root = et.Element('listings')
for item in listings:
     price = et.Element('price')
     price.text = str(item.price)
     offer = et.Element('offer', attrib={'id': str(item.pk)})
     offer.append(price)
     root.append(offer)
tree = et.ElementTree(root)
return HttpResponse(et.dump(tree), content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

Alternatively, use Django REST Framework in conjunction with the third-party djangorestframework-xml library, which allows you to flexibly define your serializers.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, hello and thanks for the reply. I did as you advised. Got an error ''xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'price''

Comment: I got a new error. **error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty.
** Recording from the terminal: `<listings><offer id="1"><price>&lt;Element 'price' at 0x05317960&gt;</price></offer><offer id="2"><price>&lt;Element 'price' at 0x05317F90&gt;</price></offer>`